Probability Selection Problem
Dave takes a $21$-question multiple-choice exam, but he did not study and randomly guesses each answer:

Each question has $3$ possible choices. Find the probability that he guesses more than $70\ \%$ of the questions correctly.
Here's what I've calculated so far. $21 \times 70\ \% = 14.7$, which means that Dave needs to answer at least $15$ questions correctly.
However, I'm not too sure how to move on from here. -
Would this equation work $?$:

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{6}{21 \choose n}{2^{n} \over 3^{21}}
$$
Any advice would be appreciated.

Can you explain how you came up with your formula? What does the ${21 \choose n}$ represent? What about the $2^n$?

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Your answer is correct. For completeness, this is a standard problem that you can tackle with the binomial probability mass function. Treat the number of questions on this test as a binomial random variable and then find the probability that he gets $Y = 15$ or more correct, which you can break up into the discrete cases of $Y=15, Y=16...Y=21$. Start with $Y=15$.
First, you have $21$ questions, each answer to which is a draw from a binary random variable with probability $\pi_i = \frac{1}{3}$ of being correct. So, the probability of any particular sequence of $15$ successes and $6$ failures (it's conventional to represent this with the first $15$ being correct, but it makes no difference) is $(\frac{1}{3})^{15} (\frac{2}{3})^6$. Because of the commutativity of multiplication, this is the probability of any sequence with $15$ successes.
That number is extremely small, but that's not the end of the story. Dave could get many other sequences that share the property of having $15$ correct answers. This is where the use of the binomial coefficient is correct. To count the number of sequences of objects that fall into two classes, where we don't care about any possible swapping of identical objects, we find the number of ways to arrange all $n!=21!$ objects and then divide by spurious permutations of the objects in each class, $k_1!k_2! = 15!6!$. Dividing the first quantity by the second gives us the regular binomial coefficient, $\binom{21}{15} = \frac{21!}{15!6!} = 54,264$.
If we multiply those two numbers together, we'll have the number of sequences to get $15$ items correct multiplied by the probability of any such sequence, which is still small, but it's not vanishing: $0.0003...$
To complete the problem, I would first recommend figuring out the generic formula for $Y=k$ for some $k$ and then writing a sum over it as appropriate. If you want, here is the generic answer.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[Y = k] = \binom{n}{k} \pi^k (1 - \pi)^{n-k} \cr
\mathbb{P}[Y \geq k] = \sum_{j=k} ^n 
 \left\{ \binom{n}{j} \pi^j (1 - \pi)^{n-j} \right\}
\end{align*}
$$
And here is your final probability.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[Y \geq 15] = \sum_{j=15} ^{21} 
 \left\{ \binom{21}{j} \frac{1}{3}^j (1 - \frac{1}{3})^{21-j} \right\} \approx 0.0004
\end{align*}
$$
For practical calculation purposes, you can plug the above into Wolfram Alpha, but the Online Stat Book calculator here works. Here's some very hack-ish Python code.
import numpy as np
import math
def binom(n, k):
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(k) // math.factorial(n - k)
vals = np.arange(15, 22)
p = 1/3
total_prob = 0
for j in vals:
    n = 21
    prob_j = binom(n, j) * p**j * (1-p)**(n-j)
    total_prob = total_prob + prob_j
print(total_prob)

Comparing it to your answer, you basically did the same thing, but in reverse and with slightly unusual notation. You noted that up to six failures were allowed and simplified the probability of any particular sequence of $n$ failures: $=(\frac{1}{3})^{21-n}(\frac{2}{3})^n = \frac{1}{3^{21-n}} \frac{2^n}{3^n} = \frac{2^n}{3^{21}}$. Then, you multiplied by the number of ways to obtain $6$ failures out of $21$, $\binom{21}{n}$ for $n= 0, 1, ...6$ and summed over $n$ in that set. One reason for the standard way of writing this out, however, is that it makes clearer the connection with problems where the probability is not easy to represent as a fraction.
